# Strange behavior in filter (dplyr on R)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So, I have been using nflfastR package. I have constructed a dataset containing QB's stats for 2021 NFL Season.
I have a column with the player name (player_name) among others. I can access via filter (dplyr) the  rows from those columns, but when I try to do so for player_name column I got an empty dataframe (0 rows and the number of columns equal to the standard, in my case 16).
What could be happening here?

```
Building the dataset 
qb_21<- stats_2021 %>%
  group_by(player_name, recent_team) %>%
  summarise(comp= sum(completions, na.rm= TRUE), 
            att= sum(attempts), 
            perc= (comp/att)*100, 
            pass_y= sum(passing_yards), 
            tds= sum(passing_tds), 
            int= sum(interceptions), 
            sacks= sum(sacks), 
            two_pt= sum(passing_2pt_conversions), 
            air_yards= sum(passing_air_yards), 
            epa= sum(passing_epa, na.rm= TRUE), 
            carries= sum(carries), 
            rush_yards= sum(rushing_yards), 
            rush_tds= sum(rushing_tds), 
            total_tds= tds + rush_tds)%>%
  filter(att >= 30) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
When running this, I got the "empty" dataframe 
qb_21 %>%
  filter(player_name== "A. Dalton")
```

I tried to filter by player (rows) but I didn't manage to get a dataframe of 1 line and 16 columns as expected.

Comment: please provide the script you used to retrieve the data you are calling stats_2021

Comment: stats_2021<- load_player_stats(2021)

Comment: stats_2021<- load_player_stats(2021)
stats_2021 is a format nflversedata but I attributed that to qb_21 which is a tibble

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

There's no space in A.Dalton:

```r
qb_21 %>% filter(player_name== "A. Dalton")
```

```
# A tibble: 0 x 16
```

When you remove the space to match the actual string:

```r
qb_21 %>% filter(player_name== "A.Dalton")
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 16
```